# Adding value to array without using loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I was wondering if it's possible to add a values to an array without using loops.

Yes, I know that technically I can write :

```
$myArray = array(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32); //etc...
```

But as you can see on the example if the line is very long it's smarter to do it with a loop.

Now since I already know that each number will be raised by +2 I was wondering if there is internal php command right of the box so I can do it with a callback or any other magic trick ;)

Not the correct syntax but just so you can get the idea.

```
$myArray = Array();
$myArray[] = insertArray($valueOf{$x};$x;$x>=100;$x=+2);
```

Yea, I know that this can also applied as a function/class but I'm asking if I can do that magic RIGHT OF THE BOX :)

Thanks!

Comment: Magic in coding?? Coding Itself is creating magic.

Comment: if you know that the sequence is 0,2,4,..... you don't need to store in array because you know ith number is 2*(i-1) ( 1 based index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array containing a range of elements using `range()` it supports `skip` parameter

```
$a = range(0,10,2);
print_r($a);

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 10
)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add an example for OP, otherwise it's a nice answer

Comment: SUPERB! :)))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: @iprophesy Please don't spam with smiles and so on also don't use caps! You can write something like: Thanks this worked for me or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have something called [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). Define a function like this:

```
function addTwo (&$item, $key)
{
    $item = $item * 2;
}
```

Then use the function this way:

```
array_walk ($myArray, 'addTwo');
```

In your use case, you can either use `range()` with the `skip` option or, you can use this way:

```
array_walk (range (0, $max));
```

Or, with `range()`:

```
range (0, $max, 2);
```

Comment: And how is this adding an element to an array?

Comment: @violator667 Err... Yeah, fine. All possible ways I said.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `range()` ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)). To produce your array do:

```
$array = range(0, 32, 2);
```

The last variable is the number of steps to make between each entry in the array. It defaults at one but by setting it to 2 each number will increment by 2.

```
print_r($array);
```

produces

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 14
    [8] => 16
    [9] => 18
    [10] => 20
    [11] => 22
    [12] => 24
    [13] => 26
    [14] => 28
    [15] => 30
    [16] => 32
)
```

Comment: And why a -1? This answers the OPs question.